# Reading data from ip address and port number

Tags: java

I want to read data which is flowing on some particular IP address and port number.I have code to read data using java socket programming.Here is my code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ServerTcpip {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String line=null;
        System.out.println("Waiting for client request");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5566);
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
         System.out.println("Client connected");
        DataInputStream input =  new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        while((line = sc.nextLine() )!= null){
            System.out.println(line);

        }

    }

}
```

So this is my code .I used serial port  utility software to check my code. SO my code is server and software is client.I'm getting data after disconnected from client.I'm not getting data while it is connected.Can any one guide me how can i resolve this problem.

And i want send data to client,for this i used

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.writeUTF("server sending data");
```

But it is also not working.Anyone please help me.

THANK YOU.

Comment: I think it is the client that causes you problems. Maybe it is buffering and your test data is too small, so sending is actually not done immediatly.

Comment: Data too small,you mean data recieving from client?

Comment: Yes, e.g. a `BufferedOutputStream` has a default buffer size of 8192 bytes. A `BufferedWriter` has a default of 8192 chars (each char has 16bit). It takes a while until they may want to write something to the `Socket`. You may use the `flush()` methods to force writing at a certain point in time.

Comment: I tried using flush method but im not getting.Actually flush() method is to push data to client,but firstly i have to read data from client and then i have to send response,So i need to read data first from client.My socket is connected to client and client is sending data but after disconnected client im getting data but i want to read data while client is connected . Is there any option in socket programming to ping client for ever 1 second or 10 seconds like polling functionality.